# How to access Ember.View property in #if helper

Tags: ember.js

In the template like this

```
  {{#if cond}}
    a
  {{else}}
    b
  {{/if}}
```

is it possible in `if` helper in handlebars template to access properties that were defined in view?

```
  App.QqqqView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "qqqq",
    cond: true
  });
```

Demo http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aZOguFIK/1/edit?html,js,output

Seems like it doesn't work, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it to look in the view.

```
  {{#if view.cond}}
    a
  {{else}}
    b
  {{/if}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aZOguFIK/2/edit